# InfoPath Security

Tags: infopath, security

here is dilemma, i have infopath form published in form library. This is for when new employees join the company. Manager needs to fill the form. Only managers have access to this library and no one else. However my manager asked me non of the manager should see other forms, they should only seen their own forms. We have Item-level Permission option on SP list but not in library. 
Is there any out of box option?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can have a SharePoint list, and style the form with InfoPath, it doesn't need to be a library. I suggest you follow that if you're still at the beginning of the whole development process.

You can also depend on views, where the default view is filtered by "created by" = current user. So each user will see document created by him/her. The manager can have a private view to see all documents.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, the filtered view save my life for now, however if the users know they can change the view and see everything. I cant really change to SharePoint list at this time as I have 500 items in my library.

Comment: No, users won't be able to see any private view. It's private and only your manager can see it. Anyone with proper permissions can have a private view. Others won't be able to see it.